# Python annotation's type for nested list with mix of numbers and lists

Tags: python, annotations, typing

It is known that an annotation's type for `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` is `List[List[int]]`. But what is the annotation's type for nested list with mix of numbers and lists `[[1, 1], 2, [1 , 1]]`?

Comment: That's not the right type for the first example. For the second you want a _union_ in the list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I fixed type for first example. Not sure about hot to use union

Comment: So read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing has evolved a lot in recent python version, after all it was introduced recently, therefore depending on which version you're using, the typing signature will be different.

Type of `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`:

| python version | type |
| --- | --- |
| >= 3.6 | `typing.List[typing.List[int]]` |
| >= 3.9 | `list[list[int]]` |

Type of `[[1, 1], 2, [1 , 1]]`:

| python version | type |
| --- | --- |
| >= 3.6 | `typing.List[typing.Union[typing.List[int], int]]` |
| >= 3.9 | `list[typing.Union[list[int], int]]` |
| >= 3.10 | `list[list[int] | int]` |